Harry Potter fanfic where Sirius Black has a daughter with telekinetic powers
I believe this was on either FictionAlley or FanFiction.Net. I can't recall names, but the plot I've mostly recalled.
The story revolves mostly around the daughter of Sirius Black and Draco. She doesn't know until the 1/2 chapter that she is Black's daughter; she was raised by her mother. She has telekinetic powers and can use magic without a wand. After she meets her father, she learns that her mother has just been killed by Voldemort. Draco comforts her and they begin to have a relationship.
I thought it was something like The Black Secret, but I can't find it now.
